# How can I define different permissions for different directories in one Document Library in SP2013?

Tags: permissions

How can I set different permissions in different directories (folders) in a document library in SharePoint 2013?

Example:

I have a site with a document library. In this document library, I have several folders like:

- price lists
- product data sheets
- product manuals
- ...

Now I want to set different permissions for reading and editing or approcing for those folders, e. g.

- Folder "price lists" can only be edited by sales manager and can only be read by sales people
- folder "data sheets" can only be edited by marketing and be viewed by "everyone"
- folder "product manuals" can only be edited by people form technical documentation, but be viewd by everyone

I know how to set permissions for the whole library, but how can I set read and edit permissions for the different folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the document library with the folders. Tick the little check box beside the folder in question. In the ribbon, there should be an option for Manage Permissions. From there you will have to break the permissions inheritance (there should be a link or option called Edit permissions). Once the inheritance is broken, you can add or remove people as needed.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx#BM14

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-set-unique-permissions-for-folders-and-documents/